# al intentar registrar un usuario desde mi sitio web me sale error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

me sale este error en Laravel 5.7[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\MyResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'address', 'username'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function carts()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Cart::class);
    }

    public function getCartAttribute()
    {
      $cart = $this->carts()->where('status', 'Active')->first();
      if($cart)
      {
        return $cart;
      }

      // else
      $cart = new Cart();
      $cart->status = 'Active';
      $cart->user_id = $this->id;
      $cart->save();

      return $cart;
    }


    /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitamos información, que forma tiene tu tabla de users?

Comment: ya subi el codigo de User.php ahi esta la columna 'username'

Comment: Ese es el modelo, según el error el fallor esta en la tabla en MySQL, asegurate de que la tabla este bien formada.

Comment: y en la estructura de tu tabla `User` tienes esa columna?

Comment: ahi esta la foto la columna username si aparece

Comment: sera porque estoy intentando registrar un usuario que ya esta registrado?

Comment: como hago para manejar esto como una excepcion?

Comment: es decir dos usuarios no pueden tener el mismo username y esto me pasa al intentar registrar otro usuario con el mismo username que debo hacer para mostrar un mensaje de "nombre ya usado" o algo asi

Comment: laravel lo simplifica con validaciones, acá un poco de documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique

Comment: en que parte deberia poner el unique: ?

Comment: porque en users tengo $table->string('email')->unique();

Comment: ya le agregue el unique y el error aun esta

Comment: Teneis que agregarlo en el controller o tambiem podeis hacerlo con un Request, te dejo un tutorial que te puede ayudar, es bastante claro https://laraveles.com/la-forma-mas-inteligente-para-que-hagas-validaciones-en-laravel/

Comment: Gracias lo voy a leer